# System.InvalidOperationException Error on Web Api call from React App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have these two Web Api Controllers, I am currently calling the controller method, `GetSingle` from a react applicaication

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllData()
    {
        var modelitems = new List<TestModel>();

        var items = AWEntity.GetProducts();
        var i = 0;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var model = new TestModel
            {
                Id = item.ProductId,
                TestName = item.Name,
                TestMessage = "My Message" + i,
                ReorderPoint = item.ReorderPoint
            };

            modelitems.Add(model);

            i++;
        }

        return Ok(modelitems);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetSingle()
    {
        var item = AWEntity.GetProduct();

        var model = new TestModel
        {
            Id = item.ProductId,
            TestName = item.Name,
            TestMessage = "My Message" + 1,
            ReorderPoint = item.ReorderPoint
        };

        return Ok(model);
    }
```

react `fetch` looks as such

```
    fetch('http://localhost:51620/api/TestApi/GetSingle')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => {
      this.setState({
        items : result
      }
    )
  })
```

and my WebApi route config looks as such:

```
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

So, My problem is that whenever I call the `GetSingle` method, I get this error
in the console

```
    {
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGetData on type WebAPIComponent.Controllers.TestApiController\r\nGetSingle on type WebAPIComponent.Controllers.TestApiController",
  "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "stackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Any idea what the reason might be,  I tried adding another route to the default which includes the action parameter but that didnt seem to work and If possible I would like to avoid having to use custom route attribute

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured out the answer, the route config was set up the wrong way round, the config with the action should come first as a priotity